# How can I use SignalR Hubs / Proxies without SignalR connection?

Tags: asp.net, sockets, tcp, proxy, signalr

Here is my situation:

I have a 4-tier web application consisting of browser, web server, application servers and database.

Browser and application server should communicate in a RPC-style way.

The backend will run on windows machines, so I will use IIS as web server The application needs real time communication between application server and browser.

I want to use a SignalR connection for the communication between browser and web server. For the communication between web server and application server's I want to use a plain TCP connection.

I think this approach will enable me to send JSON messages between browser and application servers. But how can I realize a RPC communication?

**Can I write a SignalR Hub, generate a JS proxy and bind the Hub to a TCP socket?**

Here is a picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xeaja4dos4bgvbz/SignalR_Hubs_Stackoverflow.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. SignalR is based on HTTP not TCP directly. WebSockets is the closest thing to a raw tcp socket and it has the added benefit that it works over port 80.

Comment: Is there any chance to just use the code which generates a JS proxy out of a (hub)  c# class?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: AFAIK signalr generates JS proxies out of c# hub classes. So it generates serializer and deserializer code for client and server. So my question was: Might it possible that I only use this generator code of the signalr library?

Comment: What does that have to do with using TCP? That code doesn't do anything fancy, and sure you can use it but I'm not sure what it'll get you but here it is https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't have something to do with TCP directly. But it could help me implementing a RPC communication between application server and browser where JS proxies are automagically created out of c# classes.